# How to intersect list in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following list of *Item* objects in c#:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Orders { get; set; }
}

List<Item> item = new List<Item>() { 
               new Item() { Id = 1, Code = 23, Orders = new List<string>() { "A", "B" }},
               new Item() { Id = 2, Code = 24, Orders = new List<string>() { "C", "D" }},
               new Item() { Id = 1, Code = 23, Orders = new List<string>() { "E", "F" }},
               new Item() { Id = 3, Code = 25, Orders = new List<string>() { "G", "H" }}
              };
```

I want to concat the Orders whose Id is same, so the output of above list should be:

```
    { 
      new Item() { Id = 1, Code = 23, Orders = new List<string>() { 'A', 'B', 'E', 'F' },
      new Item() { Id = 2, Code = 24, Orders = new List<string>() { 'C', 'D' },
      new Item() { Id = 3, Code = 25, Orders = new List<string>() { 'G', 'H' }
    };
```

How can i do this efficiently in c# ( using linq if possible ) ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek I know that

Comment: -1 Then, because you make it harder for us to help you. (I'm talking about the upper code fragment, not the lower one)

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek but the code is just for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to group the items based on their ID, and then create a new sequences based on all of the `Orders` for that group.

```
var query = items.GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Select(group => new Item
    {
        Id = group.Key,
        Orders = group.SelectMany(item => item.Orders).ToList()
    });
```

Note that this is not the *intersection* of any data.  You're getting the *union* of all data within each group.

Comment: This is a concatenation or UNION ALL (in SQL terms). A UNION would require a `.Distinct()`. Not clear which variant the OP wants.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, it may be a list-based union rather than a set-based union.  Both are trivial to implement.  I was using the work "union" in a somewhat more general sense

Comment: @Servy I have some others properties also in Item object like DateTime, Ids etc how these properties will be copied in new Item object which you are creating in SELECT ??

Comment: @user1740381 You'll need to copy them manually, if you need them in your results.  You'll need to find some logical means of aggregating them; either by ensuring that differing values of those members are put in different groups (meaning group on those fields as well) or combining the differing results in some way.

Comment: But i am not getting those in intellisence which i write `group.` ?

Comment: @user1740381 See the edit to my comment.  You need to know how to handle them; conceptually you have a list of all of them; you need to figure out how to get that list of items into whatever you want to have in your results.

Comment: @Servy can you please give me an example code for this, i am newbie with linq. thanks!

Comment: @user1740381 That depends entirely on what you want to do.  Currently you have a number of different values for each field; one for each item in the group.  What do you *want* to do with them?

Comment: @Servy check my edit in question, if i have `Code` property as mentioned their and i want to get it in the output, how will i copy in SELECT ??

Comment: @user1740381 That in no way answers my question.  In your results you have *multiple* code values, not *one* code value.  How do you plan to get one code value from the many?  Choose one at random, get the average, sum them, count them?  Do you want items with different code values but the same id to be in different groups, rather than the same group?

Comment: @Servy may be i am not clear with my question, any way thanks for help?

Comment: Probably something like `Code = group.First(item => item.Code)` will do. Alternative: `GroupBy(item => new { item.Id, item.Code })` and then `Id = group.Key.Id, Code = group.Key.Code`.

Answer (score 2):

You can group your items by their `id`, then create new item for each `id` concatenate the orders:

```
item.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new Item
                 { 
                      Id = x.Key,     
                      Orders = x.SelectMany(a => a.Orders).ToList()
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears what you want is something like this:

```
var output = items.GroupBy(i => i.Id)
                  .Select(g => new Item() 
                          {
                              Id = g.Key
                              Orders = g.SelectMany(i => i.Orders)
                                        .ToList()
                          });
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var output = 
    from i in items
    group i by i.Id into g
    select new Item() 
           {
               Id = g.Key
               Orders = g.SelectMany(i => i.Orders).ToList()
           };
```